# PBS equivalent of 'top' command: avoid running 'qstat' repeatedly

Tags: monitoring, top, scheduling, batch-jobs

When I run several jobs on a head node, I like to monitor the progress using the command `top`.

However, when I'm using PBS to run several jobs on a cluster, `top` will of course not show these jobs, and I have resorted to using 'qstat'. However the `qstat` command needs to be run repeatedly in order to continue monitoring the jobs. `top` updates in real-time, which means I can have the terminal window open on the side  and glance at it occasionally while doing other work.

Is there a way to monitor in real-time (as the `top` command would do) the jobs on a cluster that I've submitted using the PBS command `qsub`?

I was surprised to see so little, after extensive searching on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be a super-boss, you can always use 'pbstop'

It's basically a PBS cluster version of what 'htop' is for local processes.

(Note that your cluster may not have this installed. Ask the admins for it!)

(Also, supports interactive filtering by user, queue, etc)

EG:

[image]

Comment: Also, if you haven't used 'htop' for local processes, I'd suggest checking it out.

Answer (score 17):

Why not use `watch` to update qstat at a regular interval?

`watch --interval=0.5 qstat` will refresh the terminal with the output of qstat every 0.5 seconds. It doesn't quite satisfy your request of not running `qstat` repeatedly, but it's not manual at all.

Comment: Because I wasn't aware of the command. Thank you ;)

Comment: Note that not all versions of `watch` will support sub-second intervals. I tested with `watch -v` --> "0.2.0" and `watch -v` --> "watch from procps-ng 3.3.10", and neither supported the value 0.5.